# Having a HTTP request within another request and then updating the UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, asynchronous, nsurlconnection

I have an HTTP request within another request, as the second request relies on the first request's response. This will be contained in a single method that will be used within multiple view controllers.

What is the best way to go about asynchronously wrapping a request within another request?
I would like to update the UI of an iOS app based on the response of the second request. At the same time I don't want the "request code" inside each view controller as I would prefer that to be another class of its own. What is the best way to go about decoupling the UI view controller code and the request code?

Thanks

Comment: This is sort of a broad question, but ill take a go at it. 

First, for the decoupling issue, I would make a [request]Manager to handle the networking code. It's interface would use blocks something like, "[request]WithSuccess:block failure:block;" You would put whatever ui code into the success block and handle your failure cases in the failure block.

The internals of the manager would run the success block after the final request succeeded or call the failure block along the way if something messed up.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I use [AFNetworking](http://afnetworking.com/).

Generally you subclass AFHTTPClient, but here is a bare example

```
AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
[client registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
[client setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];

[client getPath:@"api1" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [client getPath:@"api2" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Yay! success!!
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // ERROR in API 2
    }];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // ERROR in API 1
}];
```

---

An example subclass of AFHTTPClient that simplifies setup.

```
@interface MyHTTPClient : AFHTTPClient
@end

@implementation MyHTTPClient
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    if (self) {
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Now in your view controller, skip setting up the operation class and the Accept header.

```
MyHTTPClient *client = [[MyHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

[client getPath:@"api1" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    [client getPath:@"api2" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        // Yay! success!!
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        // ERROR in API 2
    }];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    // ERROR in API 1
}];
```

---

Here is an example that simplifies the setup and creates a custom client API.

```
typedef void (^MySuccess)(id JSON);
typedef void (^MyFailure)(NSError *error);

@interface MyJSONClient : AFHTTPClient
- (void)getJSONSuccess:(MySuccess)success failure:(MyFailure)failure;
@end

@implementation MyJSONClient
- (void)getJSONSuccess:(MySuccess)success failure:(MyFailure)failure
{
    [self getPath:@"api1" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [self getPath:@"api2" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
            success(responseObject);
        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            failure(error);
        }];
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            failure(error);
    }];
}
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    if (self) {
        [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
        [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

Now in your view controller, use the custom method.

```
MyJSONClient *client = [[MyJSONClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];

[client getJSONSuccess:^(id JSON) {
    // Yay! success!!
} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    // ERROR in API
}];
```

Comment: Are you saying each "viewcontroller" should be a subclass of AFHTTPClient? or that the code doing http requests should be a subclass of AFHTTPClient?

Comment: @user1530580 No. Generally a subclass of AFHTTPClient would be something like MyHTTPClient that would take care of the setup and have methods specific to your data. That subclass would be used by your view controllers.

Comment: @user1530580 I think I confused things a bit here. Subclass AFHTTPClient to avoid repeated setup work and/or to simplify the client API. I'll throw in an example.